# Good practice for finding existing instance of a class from another class that is not a child

Tags: java, class, oop, instance

I'm trying to develop simple TowerDefense game but
it seems like I miss the very basics of OOP as I encountered problem
must be somehow fixable as everyone programming in OOP must have 
enountered it.

Here's very very basic structure

```
Game
|__ Map

Player
|__ UnitController

+ Block
+ Unit
```

So basically `Map()` controller creates 100 `new Block()` passing `x and y` coordinates to it
and stores information about those `Blocks()` inside a `List<>`. One of those `Block` is starting 
position (it's still a Block object).

Now `UnitController()` has `SpawnUnit()` method. It creates `new Unit()` and it (here comes the problem)
has to put this unit instance ON the starting block. In order to do that, `UnitController` will have to 
ask `Map` for starting position (that is a variable stored by `Map`) but.. **How does the UnitController**
can contact Map instance. The only way I see is that Map is a singleton and I simply can do `Map.getStartingPos`
otherwise if Map is not a singleton (thus instance) then how UnitController will find this instance? 
I *could* pass this instance to UnitController when I was instantiating UnitController but that's not an option I guess
because there'll be tons of other examples in this game (for example Towers which attacks units, it has to find a unit and ...)
and I can't simply throw those instances all around the code?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you against giving the `UnitController` a reference to its `Map`?

```
public UnitController {

    private final Map map;

    public UnitController(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Now your `UnitController` has a reference to the `Map`.  And this makes sense, if you think about it.  What units can be controlled without a map?  Shouldn't all `UnitController`s have a `Map` on which they are controlling units?  It makes sense as a property, does it not?

You certainly don't want to make `Map` a singleton, as you suggest, as this sort of breaks the elegant object-orientedness of your model.  The whole point is to be able to have multiple `Map`s, on which multiple `UnitController`s can be acting.  Restricting this to one run at a time, one `Map` at a time, makes the code much more procedural than object-oriented.

No matter what you do, the `Map` and the `UnitController` will have to have *something* in common in order to share data, even if you don't want them to have direct references to each other.

As far as "towers which attack the nearest unit" being a reason not to use this model, it doesn't make sense; a `Tower` ought to simply request the nearest unit from the `Map` object (i.e., `map.getNearestUnit(int x, int y)`).  No need for any more convoluted references, as long as everything can push and pull information from the `Map`.

For a more complicated example of the threaded `Tower` you're concerned with:

```
public class Tower extends Unit implements ActionListener {

    private final Timer fireTimer;
    private final Map map;
    private int damage;
    private int range;

    public Tower(Map map, int damage, int range, int fireRate) {
        this.map = map;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.range = range;
        fireTimer = new Timer(fireRate, this);
        fireTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == fireTimer) {
            map.damageNearestUnit(this, range, damage);
        }
    }

}
```

... where the signature for `map.damageNearestUnit` is something like `damageNearestUnit(Unit unit, int range, int damage)`.  This should essentially take the passed in `Unit`, get its coordinates, and find the nearest unit in the `int range`.  If one exists in range, deal the `int damage` to that other unit.  Then if the damaged `Unit` has less than 1 health, it should be removed from the `Map`, trigger a UI change, etc.

Actually, if I had simple getters and setters in my `Tower` and had my `damageNearestUnit` method assume that one unit was damaging another, I could simply have its signature be `damageNearestUnit(Unit attacker)`.

I hope this shows how the `Map` is the fabric that binds everything else together and controls that which exists on it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I was worried that as the game expands I'll find it very inconvenient when I will start using threads and I'll have to pass Map/Unit objects to every Tower thread so that they can deal damage, slow down unit etc

Comment: @Mike I'm suggesting that you should never have to give a `Unit` object to a `Tower`.  The `Map` should do most of the heavy lifting.  For example, in a simple tower defense game, you could just have the tower call something like `map.damageNearestUnit(int x, int y, int range, int damage)` and have the `Map` handle everything else.  Really your `Tower` thread would only be responsible for calling this method incrementally at whatever your fire rate is.

Comment: @Mike But yes, it makes sense to have to give every object on the field a reference to the shared controller that binds them all together.  They need to be able to interact.  If you make the `Tower` an island with no reference to the `Map`, then the `Map` can change the state of `Tower`, but never vice versa.

Comment: Ok Jeff. Thanks a lot. I'll post in the same thread if I found some more complicated example of the same issue (hopefully I won't :-) )

Comment: @Mike :)  Good luck!  Stuff gets complicated once you get into threading issues.